# Sequentially updating inventory values via Access VBA

Tags: loops, ms-access, multidimensional-array, vba

I need to subtract Safety Stock from an Inventory Table by item by Lot#-Location, with greatest Qty first until the Safety stock is depleted.

I can have multiple Inventory items with different Lot# Location Qty combinations.

The only relationship is Item Number

I think I am going wrong with the loop that subtracts the safety stock and then updates the Inventory table. If there is a better way to do this please let me know.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Item       Safety_Stock
011901              917

Item         Location   Lot          QOH
011901       PR501106   REXI0474    3325
011901       pp46321b   REXI0474     475
```

```vbs
Public Function InventoryUpdate()
Dim intTot As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim i2 As Integer
Dim loopCounter As Integer

'Assign recordsets

'Define recordset to get expected SS data
Dim rsSS As DAO.Recordset
Set rsSS = Currentdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl_ItemxSS")

'Define recordset to get Inventory data
'Inventory records ID, Site, PL, Item, Desc, Location, Lot, QOH, QtyAlloc, Created, Expire, Status
Dim rsInv As DAO.Recordset
Set rsInv = Currentdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl_Inventory")

' get rsSS.recordcount and go back to the beginning
rsSS.MoveLast
rsSS.MoveFirst
'Debug.Print rsSS.RecordCount


' Need to update Inventory records returned by subtracting SS 
Dim RA() As Variant
ReDim RA(0 To rsSS.RecordCount - 1, 0 To 1)

' Populate the array with the SS data
i = 0
Do Until rsSS.EOF
'Debug.Print rsSS.Fields(0)
'Debug.Print rsSS.Fields(1)
    RA(i, 0) = rsSS!Item
    RA(i, 1) = rsSS!Safety_Stock

    If rsSS.RecordCount <> 0 Then
        rsSS.MoveNext
        i = i + 1

    End If
Loop

intTot = 0
loopCounter = 0 ' This will ensure we don't check transactions more than once

Do Until rsInv.EOF
Debug.Print rsInv.Fields(3)
 Debug.Print rsInv.Fields(7)

    If intTot < rsInv!QOH Then                      'if 0 is less than QOH
        For i = loopCounter To UBound(RA)           'Loop through SS array one by one
            intTot = intTot + RA(i, 1)              'Initialize intTot to be SS Qty
            If intTot <= rsInv!QOH Then             'If SS Qty <= QOH
                rsInv.Edit                          'Edit Inventory Table
                rsInv!QOH = rsInv!QOH - intTot      'Subtract SS from QOH
                rsInv.Update                        'Update that QOH's with new Qty
                intTot = 0                          'Reset SS qty to 0 since it was all allocated
                loopCounter = loopCounter + 1       'increase this so we don't double check a transaction
                Exit For ' exit loop and move to the next SS Qty
            End If
        Next i
    Else
        rsInv.Edit
        rsInv!QOH = rsInv!QOH
        rsInv.Update
        intTot = intTot - rsInv!QOH
    End If
    If rsInv.RecordCount <> 0 Then
        rsInv.MoveNext
    End If
Loop
End Function
```

Comment: What is the error?  Or what is happening that shouldn't be and vica versa?

Comment: There is no error message. But the code does not subtract the safety stock from the quantity on hand and update with the new qty. It is not updating the quantity on hand after looping through the Inventory table. That is:  Looping through the Invnetory table by item and subtracting the associated item's Safety stock from the quantity on hand and then moving on. I am not sure what I am missing to make this happen correctly.

Comment: I would try using `Debug.Print rsInv!QOH` after the row `rsInv!QOH = rsInv!QOH - intTot` and keep using that `Debug.Print` on whatever is supposed to return/update a value.  Then use the immediate window to see if everything is looking like it should.  Give that a shot.

Comment: Using your suggestion I can see that the code is subtracting some safety stock from each line. It appears as though I need to use a line of code to ensure It is comparing Inventory Item to Safety Stock Item? I am not 100% sure, but I think that may be a problem. Does this appear to be missing in my code? If so, could I add it with the following:  If RA(i, 0) = rsInv!Item Then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

1. As you mention in your last comment, you are not matching on [Item] between the two tables, so your table updates don't necessarily apply to the correct item.
2. Your SELECT statement for `rsInv` does not include an ORDER BY clause, so you aren't processing the Inventory records according to who has the most.
3. There is no need to dump the values from `rsSS` into an array and loop through the array; just loop through the Recordset itself.
4. Overall your code is more convoluted than it needs to be.

```vbs
Dim rsSS As DAO.Recordset, rsInv As DAO.Recordset
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim intTot As Long, intReduction As Long

Set rsSS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset( _
        "SELECT * FROM [tbl_ItemxSS]", _
        dbOpenSnapshot)
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
        "SELECT * FROM [tbl_Inventory] " & _
        "WHERE [Item]=[pCurrentItem] " & _
        "ORDER BY [QOH] DESC")
Do Until rsSS.EOF
    intTot = rsSS!Safety_Stock
    qdf!pCurrentItem = rsSS!Item  ' set query parameter for this iteration
    Set rsInv = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)
    Do Until rsInv.EOF
        intReduction = IIf(rsInv!QOH > intTot, intTot, rsInv!QOH)
        rsInv.Edit
        rsInv!QOH = rsInv!QOH - intReduction
        rsInv.Update
        intTot = intTot - intReduction
        If intTot = 0 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        rsInv.MoveNext
    Loop
    rsInv.Close
    Set rsInv = Nothing
    rsSS.MoveNext
Loop
Set qdf = Nothing
rsSS.Close
Set rsSS = Nothing
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly. Thank you for the clarification. Looping through the recordset instead of the array simplified the solution further. I appreciate your expertise. Thank You.